# JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type FacebookProfile

Tags: java, facebook, json, integration, spring-social

I connect to facebook using OAuth2.0 protocol. And everything is allright cause i get access_token on the server now i want to connect to facebook and get it API. but i recieve JSON exception. so this is the code:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String process(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory("appid", "appsecret");
        OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
        OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters("http://localhost:8080/shop/");
        String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);

        try {
            response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);
            LOG.error("ALL WORKING FINE>>>");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("Errorrrrr" + e);
        }
        String authCode = request.getParameter("code");

        LOG.error("Facebook  controller works... 1");
        LOG.error(authCode);
        if (authCode != null) {
            AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(authCode, "http://localhost:8080/shop/", null);
            LOG.error("Facebook  controller works... 2");
            Connection<Facebook> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
            LOG.error("Facebook  controller works... 3");
        }       

        return null;

    }
```

And here is the exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@531602f4; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@531602f4; line: 1, column: 2]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)

root cause

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@531602f4; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@531602f4; line: 1, column: 2]
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:415)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:213)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:165)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:50)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:46)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:42)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:30)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.setValues(AbstractConnection.java:172)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.initKey(AbstractConnection.java:135)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2Connection.<init>(OAuth2Connection.java:73)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth2ConnectionFactory.java:58)
    com.dataart.masternoy.controller.IndexController.process(IndexController.java:99)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)

root cause

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@531602f4; line: 1, column: 2]
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializer.java:746)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:683)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1923)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:135)
    org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:74)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:415)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:213)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:165)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:50)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:46)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:42)
    org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookAdapter.setConnectionValues(FacebookAdapter.java:30)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.setValues(AbstractConnection.java:172)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.AbstractConnection.initKey(AbstractConnection.java:135)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2Connection.<init>(OAuth2Connection.java:73)
    org.springframework.social.connect.support.OAuth2ConnectionFactory.createConnection(OAuth2ConnectionFactory.java:58)
    com.dataart.masternoy.controller.IndexController.process(IndexController.java:99)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

And here is my configs. I do not understand what i am doing wrong cause i doing everything like manual says: [MANUAL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
        <property name="connectionFactories">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.appId}" />
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.appSecret}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
        factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
        <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
        factory-method="noOpText" />

    <!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"> 
        <property name="customArgumentResolver" ref="facebookWebArgResolver" /> </bean> 
        <bean id="facebookWebArgResolver" class="org.springframework.social.facebook.FacebookWebArgumentResolver"> 
        <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="${facebook.appId}"/> </bean> -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys there was versions problem. with this pom it should work.

```
<org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.junit.version>4.7</org.junit.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.6.1</org.slf4j.version>

    <org.springframework.social-version>1.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.social-version>
    <org.springframework.social.facebook-version>1.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.social.facebook-version>
    <org.springframework.security.crypto-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.crypto-version>
    <org.codehaus.json-mapper>1.7.7</org.codehaus.json-mapper>
    <org.springframework.social-version-web>1.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.social-version-web>
```